# How can I create a longlist Selector A-Z using XML?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, selector

I have a list of bus stops. How can I create a long list selector, so that the list of randomly listed stops appear A-Z when it downloads the list from the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios

this article maybe can help you

Comment: I can add new items, but not sure how I can put the list instead of the data.